# count the number of columns for each row by condition on character and missing

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements, rowsum

I want to count the number of columns for each row by condition on character and missing.

For example, I have this dataset, `test`.

I want to create `num` columns, counting the number of columns 'not' in missing or empty value.

```
a<-c("aa","bb","cc","dd","",NA)
b<-c("",NA,"aa","","","dd")
c<-c("aa","",NA,NA,"cc","dd")
d<-c("aa","bb","",NA,"cc","dd")
test<-data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))

     a    b    c    d
1   aa        aa   aa
2   bb <NA>        bb
3   cc   aa <NA>     
4   dd      <NA> <NA>
5             cc   cc
6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd
```

I want to count the number of columns containing `NA` and empty value like

```
     a    b    c    d   num
1   aa        aa   aa   3
2   bb <NA>        bb   2
3   cc   aa <NA>        2
4   dd      <NA> <NA>   1
5             cc   cc   2
6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd   3
```

I tried some approach in other posts, like `rowSums`

[Count number of columns by a condition (>) for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862114/count-number-of-columns-by-a-condition-for-each-row)

```
> test$num<-rowSums(test!=c("",NA),na.rm=T)
> test
     a    b    c    d num
1   aa        aa   aa   3
2   bb <NA>        bb   0
3   cc   aa <NA>        2
4   dd      <NA> <NA>   0
5             cc   cc   2
6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd   0
```

However, it returns wrong numbers, and I couldn't find the reasons.

Would you let me know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` to count number of `NA`s or empty values in each row and then subtract it from number of columns in the dataframe.

```
test$num <- ncol(test) - rowSums(is.na(test) | test == "")
test
#     a    b    c    d num
#1   aa        aa   aa   3
#2   bb <NA>        bb   2
#3   cc   aa <NA>        2
#4   dd      <NA> <NA>   1
#5             cc   cc   2
#6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd   3
```

Comment: Deleted my answer since it was too close to yours: `rowSums(test != "" & !is.na(test))`

Comment: @sindri_baldur I think it is different enough to be a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nchar` + `rowSums`

```
test$num <- rowSums(nchar(as.matrix(test))>1,na.rm = TRUE)
```

or `%in%` + `rowSums`

```
test$num <- rowSums(`dim<-`(!as.matrix(test) %in% c("",NA),dim(test)))
```

such that

```
> test
     a    b    c    d num
1   aa        aa   aa   3
2   bb <NA>        bb   2
3   cc   aa <NA>        2
4   dd      <NA> <NA>   1
5             cc   cc   2
6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd   3
```

Answer (score 3):

Another idea using `rowSums` is to replace empty with NA, i.e.

```
rowSums(!is.na(replace(test, test == '', NA)))
#[1] 3 2 2 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach from the tidyverse which also tells you how many columns contain NAs or empty strings?

```
a<-c("aa","bb","cc","dd","",NA)
b<-c("",NA,"aa","","","dd")
c<-c("aa","",NA,NA,"cc","dd")
d<-c("aa","bb","",NA,"cc","dd")
test<-data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))

library(magrittr) #import the pipe operator

num_cols <- test %>% 
    tibble::rowid_to_column("row_id") %>% #1st add a rowid column 
    dplyr::group_by(row_id) %>% #split the data into single row groups (i.e. 
                                #row vectors)
    tidyr::nest() %>% #turn it into a list column called data
    dplyr::mutate(num_NAs = purrr::map_dbl(data, #loop over the data column of row 
                                                  #vectors using map_dbl
                                     ~sum(is.na(.))), #count the number of NAs
                  num_empty = purrr::map_dbl(data, 
                                         #count the empty strings 
                                         ~sum(. == "", na.rm = T)),
                  num_values = purrr::map_dbl(data, 
                                          #count columns without NAs or 
                                          #missing values (what you asked for)
                                          ~length(.)-sum(num_NAs, num_empty))
            ) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% #remove the grouping structure
    dplyr::select(num_NAs, num_empty, num_values) #extract only the variables you need

test_v2 <- cbind(test, num_cols)
test_v2  

     a    b    c    d num_NAs num_empty num_values
1   aa        aa   aa       0         1          3
2   bb <NA>        bb       1         1          2
3   cc   aa <NA>            1         1          2
4   dd      <NA> <NA>       2         1          1
5             cc   cc       0         2          2
6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd       1         0          3
```

Comment: While this solution requires more code than the other options, it gives you more information (should you want it). You could also easily insert a select() layer at the beginning (before the group_by layer) to only apply these counting rules to a subset of columns if you didn't want to get counts for the entire dataframe.